# Twig/PHP Displaying data by the author - 2 tables (Symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I'm relatively new to Symfony, and have an issue I just can't fix.

The for in the twig view is for "enquiry" entity, trying to pass the author from a "post" entity through the enquire controller to the view. Hope that makes sense.

Controller:

```
public function viewEnquireAction($id )
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $enquire = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Enquire')->find($id);

    $project = new Post();
    $author = $project->getAuthor(); //mutator from Post entity

    return $this->render('Bundle:Page:staff.html.twig', ['enquire' => $enquire, 'author' => $author]);
}
```

Twig:

```
{% for project in enquire %}
    {% if app.user == author.username %} //issue here.
        //return data will go here
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In essence, I'm trying to display data from the database only if the user who is logged in the author.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more general attempt that will let you re-use your "Author is allowed to see" code everywhere in your app is using **voters**:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html

You can keep your existing loop but instead of comparing the users directly you can then use something like this:

```
{% if is_granted("LIST", project) %}
  <a href="{{ path('project_edit', { 'id': project.id }) }}">show project</a>
{% endif %}
```

As mentioned one advantage is that you can also use this anywhere else for instance inside a controller:

```
public function editAction(Project $project)
{
    if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('LIST', $project)) {
        // Throw access denied exception
    }
    // ...
}
```

And you can add additional rules besides the "User is Author" check.
Maybe you want users with ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN to always see everything.
Just add this to your voter class.

Answer (score 1):

The code @davidvelilla looping over projects in enquire make more sens, thend check if the project author is the same as the logged in user, that will show only the projects of the connected user, other thing you can do is using a repository or relation between either projects and user or user and author which make sens. then use a function in the repository to get projects by user_id, which you will not have to loop over all projects which is bad practice and take load of resources.

For example you have 1000 projects in database, you have a user with 1 project. Why loading from Database 1000 projects and loop them to check if user == author while you can do `$repository->getProjectsById($user->getId());` // which load only the $projects needed(1) and no need for twig check. only data display.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable $project has just been instanciated and will contain no information about the $author except for the default one that you defined in Post.php

If your $enquire entity has the right mapping information, ONLY pass that variable to the template, and them I presume you are trying to get the author of all of the projects of that enquire. Something like this might give you a clue:

```
public function viewEnquireAction($id )
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $enquire = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Enquire')->find($id);

    return $this->render('Bundle:Page:staff.html.twig', ['enquire' => $enquire]);
}

{% for project in enquire.projects %}
    {% if app.user == project.author.username %} //issue here.
        //return data will go here
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I didn't map it as the author is mapped to another field in another entity, can you map by multiple entities? Thanks for the response.

Comment: I do not know the structure of information that you need to use. But for what I've seen in your code, you do $project = new Post(); and then $author = $project->getAuthor(); which will make "author" variable contain the default information of Post entity. Surely that's not what you are trying to get is it?

Comment: Sort of, that way I should be able to access the list of authors, and if the user logged in is the author display the relevant enquiries.